# sql server store the result of a select in a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am making a function. A select statement returns only one row with one column, say an int. How do i store this int inside a declared variable so that my function can return the variable ?

```
select sum(table_name.col1) -- this line returns only one int. How to store that
--in a declared variable ? 
from
(select 
col1, col2
--code here
)table_name
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can just Google "SQL server variables" to find this.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - I had done that already. I was getting some errors. Fixed the syntax now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Varname int
SELECT @Varname = SUM(table_name.col1) FROM etc
SELECT @Varname
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @result INT

SELECT @result = sum(table_name.col1)
from
(select 
 col1, col2
 --code here
)table_name
```